# Как в настройках профиля в поле "обо мне" перенести текст на новые строку?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника

Как в настройках профиля в поле "обо мне" перенести текст на новые строку?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа.

Comment: Две раза Enter нажмите, чтоб пустая строка была между строками.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy я стесняюсь.

Comment: @Suvitruf, у нас же разные ответы - у тебя - абзац, а у меня - перевод строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавьте в свой ответ часть про Enter и всё)

Comment: @Grundy, вопрос-дубликат прекрасен, +2/-16.

Comment: @Arhad там мой ответ висит и я тогда ещё не знал, в чём суть разницы между абзацем и разрывом строки. ))

Answer (score 5):

Есть два способа начать текст с новой строки:

- **Начать новый абзац:**

  > Line A
  >
  > Line B

  В разметке Markdown для этого нужно поставить две пустых строки подряд.

  ```
  Line A

  Line B
  ```

  В полученном HTML будут два абзаца текста в тегах `<p>` (**p**aragraph, абзац):

  ```
  <p>Line A</p>
  <p>Line B</p>
  ```
- **Разбить строку переводом каретки:**

  > Line C
  >   Line D

  Для этого ставят два пробела в конце строки.

  ```
  Line C  
  Line D
  ```

  В полученном HTML будет один абзац (`<p>`) текста, разбитый переносом строки — тегом `<br>`:

  ```
  <p>Line C<br/>Line D</p>
  ```

Заметьте, что результаты выглядят по-разному. Между абзацами вертикальный промежуток больше, чем между строками одного абзаца. Этот промежуток визуально разделяет абзацы.

Если вы хотите начать новый абзац — поставьте двойную пустую строку, а если разбить абзац переносом — то двойной пробел. Если вы сомневаетесь, то лучше ставьте две пустых строки, начинайте новый абзац.

Смотрите, какая ерунда получается, если вместо абзаца использовать `<br/>`:

> Заметьте, что результаты выглядят по-разному. Между абзацами вертикальный промежуток больше, чем между строками одного абзаца. Этот промежуток визуально разделяет абзацы.
>   Если вы хотите начать новый абзац — поставьте двойную пустую строку, а если разбить абзац переносом — то двойной пробел. Если вы сомневаетесь, то лучше ставьте две пустых строки, начинайте новый абзац.
>   Смотрите, какая ерунда получается, если вместо абзаца использовать `<br/>`:

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно - так же, как и везде - в конце предыдущей строки поставить 2 пробела.

Comment: Lol. Впервые про это узнал :D

Comment: @Suvitruf Век живи - век ходи на стэковерфлоу (узнаешь много нового).